# MVC data annotaion for validating data type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, types, data-annotations

How do you customize data annotation validation for this scenario.

I am receiving this error:

> The value 'Select Province' is not
>   valid for Province.

I want it like this

> Please select a country

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
    [DisplayName("Province")]
    [UIHint("ProvinceDropDown")]
    public long? ProvinceId { get; set; }
```

My View is a select list :

```
<select name="ProvinceId" id="ProvinceId" class="input-validation-error">
    <option value="">Select Province</option>
    <option value="613">Allen </option>
    <option value="614">Anderson</option>
   // data truncated ....
</select>
```

Comment: I've never seen `UIHintAttribute` before - what does it do? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Country"` to your annotation attribute, similar to [the example here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664638%28PandP.50%29.aspx)

```
[Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Quantity on order must be between 0 and 50.")]
public int OnOrder { get; set; }
```

Comment: on what attribute will I add ErrorMessage. AFAIK it can only be attached to validation attributes. But, I don't have any. It's firing up error because "Select Province" doesn't have a value.

Comment: @geocine: To get the validators add "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;" and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll as a reference.

Comment: @CRice you got me wrong here , I know how to add the validators. Try my test case. I don't have any validation attribute for the ProvinceID property so I can't attach any error message. Using Robert's example, you could set an error message because you have a range validation attribute. The error message is shown on view everytime a rule violation for range is violated. I don't have any rules, but a default error of invalid type pops out.

Comment: At the risk of sounding simplistic, why don't you just add an annotation attribute, like `[Required]`? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx)

Comment: I thought about that too, but its a nullable long for a reason, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To customize the validators you can inherit from ValidationAttribute:

```
public class SomeAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
    }
}
```

I think you won't need to do this but instead should try making your nullable long a string, and having the validators on this property.

```
public string ProvinceId { get; set; }
```

Then converting your View Model to some domain model which has the nullable long once the validation has passed.